# My lambda function randomly crashes and throws a socket hang up error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-redis

I have serverless API which saves and fetch data in Redis mostly it runs fine but randomly throws 502 error (socket hang up) which I can't even handle inside the lambda.

````
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "socket hang up",
"code": "ECONNRESET",
"stack": [
"Error: socket hang up",
" at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)",
" at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)",
" at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)",
" at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)",
" at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
]
}```

I am using:
Nodejs 12.x
Redis: 2.8.0
````

Answer (score -2):

AWS Lambda functions have a timeout of 3-900 seconds, with 3 seconds being the default. If your Lambda does not have the timeout configured, and it takes more than 3 seconds to execute, you will get these errors.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html

Comment: Thanks but my timeout is 10 seconds